# numba jit lists as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

here is my code for this. I just want to know what I need to put to use list as input

x, y, and angle are floats
objects is a list

```
specs = ['float64(float64, float64)', 'float64(float64, float364)', 'float64(float64, float64)', ]
@numba.jit(specs, target_backend='gpu')
def ray(x, y, direction, objects):
    distance = [0, 0]
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        for i in range(len(objects)):
            xcheck = False
            ycheck = False
            if objects[i][0] < x < objects[i][0] + objects[i][2]:
                xcheck = True
            if objects[i][1] < y < objects[i][1] + objects[i][3]:
                ycheck = True
            if xcheck and ycheck:
                return distance
        tempdistance0 = numpy.sin(direction)
        tempdistance1 = numpy.cos(direction)
        distance[0] += tempdistance0
        distance[1] += tempdistance1
        count += 1
        if count > 200:
            return distance
```

the main reason I am using numba here is because it is slow in just regular python and the rest of my project is in python.

I have been trying to make this code faster for a few hours and I finally reached this but I have no clue what data type to use for this.

Comment: `target_backend='gpu'` is useless. There is no chance this code can run on a GPU as it is and even if it could, it would be inefficient on such hardware (GPUs are not faster CPUs or just CPUs with more core, but a very different architecture that require your code to be SIMD-friendly).

Comment: You cannot operate on CPython dynamic objects in Numba `njit` functions. Typing is what makes Numba fast, so operating on object would be nearly pointless. There is a compatibility mode supporting object (`jit(nopython=True)`), but it only speed up loops a bit (not their content). You need to find a fixed type for your objects for this code to be fast. Once done, then you can specify this to Numba (Numba can find the signature for you in this case, though the compilation will be done lazily).

Comment: Last but not least, it looks like the algorithm you use is not efficient. Indeed, if you have many objects, you can sort them and use a *binary search* to find matching values much faster (instead of the possibly slow inner loop). The double condition make things a bit more complex but it might be faster than using Numba blindly.

Comment: By the way, `tempdistance1 = np.sqrt(1-tempdistance0**2)` (though the sign needs to be corrected). This computation can be faster than using a `cos`.

Comment: If you use nopython mode (which is recommended), you can remove `specs` argument. Then convert `objects` to a numpy array (outside the ray function) and pass it to the ray function and see what happens.